# Clarification requested about nominees' "statistics" posted on the 2013 Moderator Election page

Tags: support

On the Nominations page, why is it "**meta** participation" that is used to describe nominees' participation and not just "site participation" or "Ask Ubuntu participation" or "Stack Exchange participation"?

Example:

meta participation
questions: a / +aa
answers: b / +bb
helpful flags: ccc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [FEichinger](https://askubuntu.com/users/98085/feichinger) said [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7987693#7987693):

> 1. Except for helpful flags, the data is from meta.
> 2. The participation data itself is meta-data.
> 3. Meta participation is "more important" in regards to a moderator's work, as it pretty much details how to deal with what, which is the
>      kind of stuff a moderator has to sort out.

Comment: Thanks for moving this here ... Fell asleep shortly before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

Meta participation on the site you nominated yourself is important due to the fact that shows your connection in the discussion of the several site's aspects, policy and governance.

Together with the rest of the stats, it easily displays *how involved* you are with the site you would be moderating if elected.

What you see on the stats is the Ask Ubuntu Meta site participation, not the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange participation. It is shown together with your helpful flags rate on the Ask Ubuntu main site.

Comment: Is this to say that the "helpful flags" shown is *just* from the main site, and not the sum of the helpful flags on main and meta?

Comment: Yes, only for the main site.

Comment: I thing being a moderator is like a job at a company which requires prior work experience at the same place. :D